# Changing paragraph heading style in memoir

Tags: memoir, sections-paragraphs

For changing all heading styles up to `paragraph`, I can use the same process in `memoir` (seen in MWE below).  However, this does not seem to work for `paragraph`, and no result is printed! I am not sure why `paragraph` is different, but how can I alter the heading style for it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir} 
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{s. \arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{(\arabic{section})}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{(\emph{\alph{subsection}})}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{(\roman{subsubsection})}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{(\emph{\alph{paragraph}\alph{paragraph}})}

\setsecnumdepth{subparagraph}

\let\oldsection=\section
\let\oldsubsection=\subsection
\let\oldsubsubsection=\subsubsection
\let\oldparagraph=\paragraph
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{{%
  \setsecnumformat{\thechapter\thesection\quad}%
  \oldsection{#1}}}
 
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{{%
  \setsecnumformat{{\thechapter\thesection\thesubsection\quad}}%
  \oldsubsection{#1}}} 
  \renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{{%
  \setsecnumformat{{\thechapter\thesection\thesubsection\thesubsubsection\quad}}%
  \oldsubsubsection{#1}}} 
 
  \renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{{%
  \setsecnumformat{{\thechapter\thesection\thesubsection\thesubsubsection\theparagraph\quad}}%
  \oldparagraph{#1}}} 
\begin{document}
\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
\chapter{Heading}
\section{Heading}
\subsection{Heading}
\subsubsection{Heading}
\paragraph{Heading}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why would not you take memoir chapter styles as a foundation, and only then customize the remainings? Should be easier.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Sure, that might be easier, but so would using a Word template.  I can't speak for other TeXers, but I like building things myself. The joy of TeX is getting to be the architect. I find the joy in TeXing not just in the finished product but being able to actually build it myself.  It's like baking one's own bread; even if a professional baker's bread would be better, the joy is in creating the recipe yourself

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what causes the problem but I can fix it. At the end of your redefinition of `\paragraph` add `\mbox{}` like

```
\oldparagraph{#1} \mbox{} }}
```

and presumably the same if you are redefining `\subparagraph`.

You might also consider using `\maxsecnumdepth{subparagraph}` to get all the subdivisions numbered.

Please note that `memoir`'s original sectional division macros take two optional and one required argument that you haven't catered for in your redefinitions.

As, according to your response to @OlegLobachev, you find joy in "creating the recipe itself" then look at the `memoir` definition of `\paragraph`.